# substring from indexof(word) until next line

Tags: java, android, string, substring

i want subString from `indexof("&")` until next line,my code is

```
  String substring = thisSrch.srchdesc.substring(thisSrch.srchdesc.indexOf("&"), frstNextNewLine);
```

but i dont know how i can find `frstNextNewLine`
for exmaple i want detect "**& Ali is First person that joined.**" in below text

> A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like
> these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.
>
> **& Ali is First person that joined.**
>
> I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was
> created for the bliss of souls like mine.

Comment: post here your string.. @ArMo 372

Comment: i added example

Comment: means you have to detect . or /n ?

Comment: but is multi "\n" befor and after of "& Ali is First person that joined. line"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int andIndex = thisSrch.srchdesc.indexOf("&");
String substring = thisSrch.srchdesc.substring(andIndex, thisSrch.srchdesc.indexOf("\n", andIndex));
```

The indexOf function used above accepts a parameter to starting looking for new line after the index of the '&' character.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
String substring;
for(int i=0;i<thisSrch.srchdesc.length;i++){
    if(thisSrch.srchdesc.indexOf("\n")>thisSrch.srchdesc.indexOf("&")){
      substring = thisSrch.srchdesc.substring(thisSrch.srchdesc.indexOf("&"), thisSrch.srchdesc.indexOf("\n"));
      break;
    }
}
```

This might not be efficient for large data

For more efficiency,

```
substring = thisSrch.srchdesc.substring(thisSrch.srchdesc.indexOf("&"), thisSrch.srchdesc.indexOf("\n",thisSrch.srchdesc.indexOf("&")));
```

Comment: but is multi "\n" befor and after of  "& Ali is First person that joined. line"

Answer (score 1):

`srchdesc.substring(thisSrch.srchdesc.indexOf("&"),thisSrch.srchdesc.indexOf("\n",thisSrch.srchdesc.indexOf("&")+1));`

here **substring** function will return you the substring with the two passed indexes.

First parameter,you have passed is correct.
Second parameter you have to pass is  indexOf("\n")
here *\n* identifies new line also the second parameter in indexOf is after which index you want to search "\n" so that will be your index of "&",so it will return the index of next occurrence of "\n" after "&"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
substring.split("\n")[0]
```